# How can I fix my program?

Tags: php

What is the problem with my code and how can I fix my problem?

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
$q="SELECT * FROM student WHERE Id=1";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
$count=mysql_num_rows($rs);
echo $count;
if($count!=0){
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($count)){
    echo $result['Id']."<br/>";
    echo $result['Name']."<br/>";
    echo $result['Dept']."<br/>";
    echo $result['Email']."<br/>";
    echo $result['Gender']."<br/>";
    echo $result['Cgpa']."<br/>";
    echo $result['Password']."<br/>";
}
}
else
{
    die("There is a error in database parsing");
}
?>
```

Error message:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\admin\login_admin.php on line 58
```

There is a error in database parsing

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop using `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated and will be removed entirely at some point in the future.
2. You should be doing `$result = mysql_fetch_array($result)`, not `$count`.

Comment: but you're contradicting yourself. in 2. your using mysql_*

Comment: @thelolcat I advise against using those functions while pointing out the reason the use shown isn't working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity shouldn't it be `$result = mysql_fetch_array($rs);` since `$rs` is the query result? Otherwise, won't result overwrite result?...

Comment: however you can still use it if you have PHP version <  5.5.0

Comment: @Geomorillo But you shouldn't. It's not secure.

Comment: OOPs sorry I actually use $result = mysql_fetch_array($rs); when I directly access to this php file from localhost it shows me the result but when I want to this from another php file using require_once() the it shows me the error.

Answer (score 1):

You must read this link: https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows.
Use mysql_affected_rows() instead of mysql_num_rows().